# Multiple inheritance-related confusion in Java

Tags: java

I have confusion in Java inheritance. As I studied Java does not support multiple inheritance. So that it does not have the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) of inheritance at all.

But, every class of Java inherits the *Object* class by default, and if we extend a class then there are two inherited classes first is Object and second is our inherited class. As I know if any class inherits two or more classes, it’s known as multiple inheritance. It shows that Java supports multiple inheritance, because it’s inheriting two classes at same time.

Then why it’s said that Java does not support multiple inheritance and is there a possibility to have the diamond problem in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, every class of Java inherits Object class by default, and if we extend a class then there are two inherited classes first is Object and second is our inherited class

That's partially correct.

If you extend a class explicitely, then it won't extend `Object` class.

if you have a class

```
class A
{

}
```

then, compiler will change it into

```
class A extends Object
{

}
```

But, if you extends a class explicitely, as following,

```
class A extends AnotherClass
{

}
```

compiler won't add anything now, hence No multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks.. i got that, it means there will be only one copy of Object class member in every class. So there will be no multiple inheritance.

Comment: @MouseCrasher You have fundamentally misunderstood the concept of inheritance. What you are talking about is aggregation and/or composition. When class A _inherits_ from `Object` that doesn't mean that an instance of class A has a member that is an `Object`, it means that class A **is** an `Object`.

Comment: @MouseCrasher: You got it but the way you explained it totally wrong. There will be one copy of class Object (of Object instance) in each instance of `class A`

Comment: @Azodious: <br>`class A extends AnotherClass
{

}
compiler won't add anything now, hence No multiple inheritance.`<br> This is not correct. Even if I say `class A extends AnotherClass` I can override the methods of Object class in class A. That means that class A still has a copy of (members of) Object class. So to cut the long discussion short, every class in Java has a copy of Object class.

Answer (score 6):

Since *all* classes extend `Object`, the base class you're extending is by definition already extending `Object`. Your class doesn't need to add `Object` itself since it already exists in the hierarchy.

That means, `Object` will still only exist *once* in your hierarchy as the very root, so no "diamond".

Answer (score 6):

See this:

```
OBJECT CLASS
      |
      |
CLASS A{} // Class A extends class Object
      |
      |
CLASS B{} // Class B extends class A
      |
      |
CLASS C{} // Class C extends class B
```

Since every class is inherited from the *Object* class, it is not in the case *when* you inherit from other class. Thus the object class will become super or the root class for all other inherited classes.

So there isn't any problem.

Answer (score 5):

You have misunderstood the concept of `Class extending Object` in case of `Inheritance`.

Only the top level class in the inheritance hierarchy, extends from `Object` class, and rest of the class lower in the hierarchy, extend the immediate super class. Thus they have all the methods of `Object` class through this hierarchy of `inheritance`, and there is no `multiple inheritance` involved.

```
public class A {  // Extends from `Object` class
}

class B extends A { // Extends from `A`
}

class C extends B { // Extends from `B`
}
```

So, there will be no `diamond` problem in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

```
Java supports only syntactical multiple inheritance. Java does not 
supports  implementation of multiple inheritance.
```

Some people says java supports multiple inheritance through interfaces but it's not correct here the explanation:

### inheritance ::

Getting the properties from one class object to another class object:

```
Class A{}

Class B extends A {}
```

Here an object of class B  getting the properties(methods/functions/ & data  members/class variables)
of class A.

Why java does not supports multiple inheritance  using classes:

```
Class A{}
Class B{}
Class C extends A,B{}
```

X--this statement causes error because Class A getting object of object class from both sides A and B...

Every java class by default extending Object of object class and Object of object class is the root object means super class for all classes.

But here Class C having two super classes of object so giving error means java does not support multiple inheritance by using classes.

Is java supports multiple inheritance using Interfaces:

Because of this interface concept only few of us saying that java supports multiple inheritance but it is wrong.

### Here the explanation::

```
interface A{}
interface B{}
interface C implements A , B{}
```

(or)

```
interface A{}
interface B{}

Class C implements A , B{}
```

Here its look like multiple inheritance but inheritance means getting the properties from one class object to another class object.

Here in interface concept we are not at all getting any properties rather we are implementing the unimplemented methods of interface in class.

So inheritance and intefaces are quite opposite.......

So finally java supports only syntax of multiple inheritance does not supports implementation of multiple inheritance.

Inheritance is like debit and interface is  like credit but interface has its own importance in other concepts like server side programming.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly in Java. You can only inherit from one distinct class at a time. That distinct class might inherit from another class. However, you don't have a single class inheriting from multiple distinct classes...

Answer (score 1):

The class you extend from already extends from Object. When you extend from the new class, you in effect stop extending *directly* from Object, and instead inherit it via the new direct ancestor.

So it's not that you're extending from *two different* classes, it's that you're extending from a class *that itself already extends from another class*, namely the Object class.

Visually, multiple inheritance would be:

```
  A  Object
  |   |
    C
```

But the situation you describe is actually:

```
Object
  |
  A
  |
  C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have many `ancestors` but only one parent. Here ancestors mean `Object class` where as parent mean the class which you are extending.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying a class to inherit you override the default extends Object. So only when you don't specify a class to inherit does a class extend Object.